# XSLT 2.0: <xsl:number> conditional formatting

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a client that depending on the number of total nodes present wants to vary the format for a `xsl:number` element.

For example if the total number of nodes < 101 then the format string is "01" so that 1 => will be displayed 01.

If the total number of nodes > 100 or < 1001 then the string format is "001" then 1 => 001, 99 => 099.

I have tried using a variable in the format attribute to xsl:number but I only got for the format string "001" as a result 10 => $10 instead of 010.

Is there a way to do this without using some `xsl:choose` for the possible ranges?

EDIT:

Here again the solution I found thanks to Michael's code hint:

```
 <xsl:variable name="total-number-nodes" select="count(//node)"/>
 <xsl:variable name="base-format-string" select="string('000000000000000000000001')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="fomat-string" select="substring($base-format-string, string-length($base-format-string) - string-length(string($total-number-dossiers)) + 1)"/>
 <xsl:number level="multiple" count="node" format="{$fomat-string}"/>
```

Comment: You say "I have tried using a variable in the format attribute to xsl:number" - can you edit the question to show exactly what you have tried?  The `format` attribute is treated as an AVT so you can include calculated parts in curly braces like `format="{$var}"`

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks that was part of the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:number format="{substring('000', 1, string-length(string($n)))}"/>
```

where $n is a variable holding the count of the nodes.

Comment: Thanks Michael that put me in the right track although the solution proposed didn't do what I wanted I was able to modify it to achieve it.

Comment: @Vlax "*the solution proposed didn't do what I wanted*" In what way?

Comment: sorry for the delay to answer I need to test it again but I had the impression it wasn't working but I'll come with an example soon

Answer (score 0):

I can't somehow edit the original question so here the final code I used, probably there's a more elegant solution using translate instead of using substring....

```
    <xsl:variable name="total-number-nodes" select="count(//node)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="base-format-string" select="string('000000000000000000000001')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fomat-string" select="substring($base-format-string, string-length($base-format-string) - string-length(string($total-number-dossiers)) + 1)"/>
    <xsl:number level="multiple" count="node" format="{$fomat-string}"/>
```